# Windows XAML: Replacement for WPF TextBox's CharacterCasing

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-store-apps, converters

I have a TextBox that whenever a user types into it I want the text to only be uppercase.  For example, if I type in "abc" the actual text in the TextBox and in the backend binding should be "ABC".

In WPF there is the CharacterCasing property, but I can't seem to find that in Windows XAML (or whatever you call a Windows 8 app).

I tried making a converter, but that didn't seem to work:

**Converter:**

```
 public class UpperCaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=uiMainPage, Path=Company, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ToUpper}}"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that didn't seem to work"? Note that this shouldn't be two-way since you cannot restore the original string from an all-uppercase one.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/09276ef6-556a-4fb7-9d1b-181cf84db304/windows-8-winrt-textbox-upper-case-setting

Comment: It didn't do anything to the text.  I'm confused by your last sentence there, could you elaborate?

Comment: @kennyzx I would prefer if this could be generic, so I could use it in multiple places, like a converter.  Is there any way to do that?  I'm sort-of a noob in that area....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I made for it in VB.Net but it should be easy to translate to C#

Make a `textchanged` event for your textboxes and call a method giving it your `sender` as a `textbox`

```
Private Sub AnyTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) 
    TextBoxToChange = (CType(sender,Textbox))
    TextBoxToChange.Text = TextBoxToChange.Text.ToUpper()
    TextBoxToChange.SelectionStart = TextBoxToChange.Text.Length
End Sub
```

The `TextChanged` event takes the `textbox` and changes the text to `uppercase` (The `selectionstart` is to stop the selection of the `textbox` to go back to 0 which causes to write backwards )

You will have XAML looking like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTest1"
         TextChanged="AnyTextBox_TextChanged"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtTest2"
         TextChanged="AnyTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

It is not exactly a converter as you wish but it will do the trick just fine and this will only be 1 method per `page`

Comment: Could this at all be made more generic, like a converter I can use where ever I have a reference.  But with this I would have to make it for each class I make.  Not cool duplicate code...

Comment: @ARandomGuy I have edited my post making it that you only need one method per page. It is the best I can do as I am not familiar with converters as you want them.